# Proton Quantum Tunnelling in Hydrogen Bonds: Influence on Properties of Deuterated Ice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Hydrogen bonding occurs between an atom with a bound hydrogen atom and an atom with an unbonded lone electron  pair (full molecular orbital) and is described in the literature as caused by proton quantum tunnelling between two potential wells, coupled by a potential barrier.

Take for example the $\mathrm{N:H} \to \mathrm{:N}$ system, present in DNA, which can be schematised as follows:

[image: NHN hydrogen bonding.]

Quantum mechanically the system be seen as a coupled two potential well system for the proton, separated by a potential barrier (the gap between the $\mathrm{N}$ atoms):

[image: Double proton well with barrier.]

In water ice ($\mathrm{H_2O}$) hydrogen bonds are very abundant (the dotted lines represent the hydrogen bonds):

[image: Hydrogen bonds in water ice.]

And this got me thinking about 'heavy ice', i.e. solid deuterium oxide ($\mathrm{D_2O}$). The tunnelling intensity, all other things being equal, is much reduced with increased particle mass $m$.

For example, for a rectangular potential barrier of width $a$ and height $V_0$ the transmissibility $T$ for a particle with energy $E$ is approximated by:

$$\large{T=\frac{16(k\kappa)^2}{(k^2+\kappa^2)^2}e^{-4a\kappa}},$$
$$\large{k=\sqrt{(2mE/\hbar)}}.$$
$$\large{\kappa=\sqrt{(2m(V_0-E)/\hbar)}}.$$

Clearly the tunnelling effect for a deuteron (twice the mass of a proton, approx.) is much smaller than for a proton (all other things being equal). This really suggests that tunnelling in solid $\mathrm{D_2O}$ should be much reduced.

Yet when one looks at the [bulk properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water#Physical_properties_.28with_comparison_to_light_water.29) of solid $\mathrm{H_2O}$ and solid $\mathrm{D_2O}$ the differences are very small.

*Does proton/deuteron tunnelling have little influence on the bulk properties of these solids?*

Comment: I've always understood hydrogen bonding to be a dipolar interaction. It isn't clear to me why tunnelling would be involved.

Comment: @JohnRennie: It is *primarily* a dipole interaction. But have a look at this: http://users.df.uba.ar/giribet/f4/adn.pdf. Other sources also claim tunnelling can make a contribution to reaction rates (Arrhenius).

Comment: If it's primarily a dipole interaction, with (possibly) a small contribution from tunneling, then replacing H with D will make little difference. Which is of course what we observe. I say *possibly* because I'm massively unconvinced that tunneling has **any** significant effect in hydrogen bonding.

Comment: @JohnRennie: even in the case presented in that paper?